# Getting "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main" when OTP arrives from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting

> "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main" and "
> android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService()
> did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord" as error
> when OTP arrives from firebase or after some specific time.

My code.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                "+91" + phone.getText().toString(),
                30,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                LoginUser.this,
                new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        getOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        getOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginUser.this, EnterOtp.class);
                        intent.putExtra("backEndOtp", s);
                        intent.putExtra("mobile", phone.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        getOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        finish();

                    }
                }
        );
```

I tried using try/catch in my code but it did'nt work

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces that error?

Comment: it does not say where the problem is, in log cat